# How to avoid internet explorer first button selection?

Tags: javascript, events, cross-browser

I have one form with several text fields and one button. When i enter one of the text fields, the submit button become highlighted and if i press enter while typing, the button is pressed, so i got an unexpecte behaviour because my page is submitted. Firefox doesn't act such a way.
Is there some attribute or configuration to avoid this undesired behaviour or i have to use some javascript technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally what I do in this situation is make the first button on the form do nothing and then hide it with CSS. Kludgy? Sure. Effective? Absolutely.

In fact, this is a duplicate of [Stopping IE from highlighting the first submit-button in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442548/stopping-ie-from-highlighting-the-first-submit-button-in-a-form).

Comment: I think the solution should be extended with the fact that the button should have onclick ="return false;" and also it should be hidden with width:0px.

Comment: What benefit is width:0px over display:none?

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable the Enter key for those input elements to prevent form submission.  Take a look at [this article](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Disable-Form-Submit-on-Enter-Key-Press.aspx).

Comment: It could be a good solution. In my case i preferred to use cletus'solution.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of discussion about this here: [How to prevent ENTER keypress to submit a web form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form/)