# IE7 when <input type="submit"> it have black border in bottom ,how to delete?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, input

css:

```
width:80px;
height:65px;
background: #0fe;
border:none;
outline:none;
border-bottom:3px solid #f0f;
```

Comment: Current use of IE7 is globaly: 0.13%. There is no need to support it.
Personally i find IE8 a bit far-fetched to even support.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Black border on IE7 buttons on textarea/input focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602544/black-border-on-ie7-buttons-on-textarea-input-focus)

Answer (score 0):

Use Filter:

```
input[type=submit],
input[type=reset],
input[type=button]
{
       filter:chroma(color=#000000);
}
```

Source: http://www.cssjunction.com/css/remove-black-border-around-input-buttons-in-ie-7/