# IE highlighting first submit button

Tags: asp.net, button, postback, aspbutton

I have around 10 buttons on a web app. IE keeps highlighting the first button by default. I dont want any of the buttons highlighted. I've tried adding this per [Stopping IE from highlighting the first submit-button in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442548/stopping-ie-from-highlighting-the-first-submit-button-in-a-form)

```
useSubmitBehavior="false"
```

which works fine but also disables the postback of the button.

Any other suggestions?

Update:

```
<asp:Button ID="first_btn" runat="server" Text="Some Text" 
onclick="first_btn_Click" CssClass="button" />
<asp:Button ID="second_btn" runat="server" Text="Some Text" 
CssClass="button" onclick="second_btn_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="third_btn" runat="server" Text="Some Text" 
CssClass="button" onclick="third_btn_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="forth_btn" runat="server" Text="Some Text" 
CssClass="button" onclick="forth_btn_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="fifth_btn" runat="server" Text="Some Text" 
CssClass="button" onclick="fifth_btn_Click" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Once the page is loaded, trigger

```
document.getElementById("myButton").focus();
```

supposing your button is defined as `<button id="myButton">Send</button>`.

Comment: I dont want any of the buttons highlighted

Comment: Pay attention to OP, he downvotes answers to his own questions. That's a first. Don't bother taking time to answer this guy...

Comment: Not sure who you're refering to here pal but I didnt down vote you.